# How to display some value with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-in-js

I'm new to styled-components and I'm bit confused. 
Can we display something or add functionality to styled-compoentns.
OR styled-components is component that we can apply css only

Comment: "Can we display something or add functionality to styled-components" Which functionality? What do you want to display? Please elaborate

Comment: What if I have component that takes some props and change this value according to some condition and return something ? Can I style this component with styled-component.

Answer (score 0):

styled-components is primarily intended to apply css.

So typically you would use wrapper components that provide the content and use the components obtained from styled-components for decoration.

Once in a while, I have found it useful to use the [.attrs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props) constructor to pass `children` when 
the content is very specific to the component.

```js
const ResourceMissingError= styled.div.attrs({
    children: 'This resource could not be found'
})`color: red`;

render(<ResourceMissingError />);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we display something or add functionality to styled-components?

Yes, styled components are usable as any native component would be. So just as HTML's `<button>` can be used to display something, you can use a styled button to do so. See below.

Similarly, you can add functionality as you would in a native component, by listening to click events, for instance. The demo below "adds" functionality to the `ColorfulButton` by handling its click event.

See also how the color is passed as a prop to the `ColorfulButton` via `mycolor="green"`:

```js
const ColorfulButton = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  color: ${props => props.mycolor || "blue"};
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
`;

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { text: "Learn JavaScript (click me)", done: true }
  }
  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({...this.state, done: !this.state.done});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ColorfulButton onClick={this.handleClick} mycolor="green">{this.state.text}</ColorfulButton>
        <br />
        {this.state.done ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: What if I have component that takes some props and change this value according to some condition and return something ?

Comment: How does it return this something?

Comment: return some value to render I mean

Comment: How it would differ from the `${props => props.mycolor || "blue"};` part in the demo above?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a CSS file and import it in your different components like making class in CSS and use that class in your component as `className=""`. Also, you can refer inline CSS like this way `style={{}}` make sure the properties name like `font-size` will be written in `fontSize` in React inline CSS. Every CSS property that have a dash in the middle of the property name, the dash will be removed and the next letter after dash will be capitalized and also the property value will be in double or single quotation.